# How can I replace string with regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

I replace my string as below;

```
string str = "Opps V 14";
str = str.Replace("V 14", "V14");
```

But numeric part of string is not static. Sometimes it can be "V 17", "V 13" etc..

How can I replace that with regular expressions globally?

Comment: Do you insist use regex? I think that there are other ways.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace the space between V and a digit with nothing:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\bV) (?=\d)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(str, "");
```

`(?<=\bV)` is a lookbehind assertion and means "preceded by V", `\b` is a word boundary.

`(?=\d)` is a lookahead assertion and means "followed by a digit"

Lookaround assertions are not part of the match result but only checks. This is the reason why only the space is removed.

note: you must include `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the begining of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that except the number, rest of the string is static, then its as simple as removing the space after V:

> str = str.Replace("V ","V");

Comment: and what if there is a `V ` that is not followed by a digit??

Comment: Seemed to me the question implied the non-didgit part was static, but this should be clarified. If so, regex might indeed be overkill

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Opps V 14";
        string[] temp = str.Split(' ');
        str = String.Join(" ", temp.Take(2)) + temp.Last();
    }
}
```